# double polymorphic association with same tables? any idea on how to preload them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, preload

I have CallSession table. it has polymorphic associations:

```
class CallSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :callable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :calleeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

CallSession has callable_type,callable_id,calleeable_type and calleeable_id.

the members of callable assoc are Doctor table and Consumer table, and calleeable assoc has Doctor and Consumer table. (yeah the same tables)

now, I need to query CallSession where its callable Email is different from its calleeable Email (Both Doctor and Consumer has Email,both can be callable or calleeable). One email can be used for both Doctor and Consumer object.

any idea on how to query it in one Scope with preloads to avoid N+1? thanks in advance!
at worst I will store the callable.email and calleeable.email in new columns.

Comment: I don't see how you would do this, since both relationships are polymorphic and thus you can't join them (not easily, anyway). You would have to hard-code the `callable_type` and `calleeable_type` classes into the query, it would be very ugly.

Comment: I think I'm fine with that. But if I hardcode the "consumers.email" for instance, how does the query know if what I mean is consumer as the callable, not the calleeable?